# How to create a TCP server in Deno natively?

Tags: javascript, tcp, deno

This example is taken from the documentation, but it only does echo.

```
const listener = Deno.listen({ port: 8080});
console.log("listening on 0.0.0.0:8080");

for await (const conn of listener) {
    Deno.copy(conn, conn).finally(() => conn.close());
}
```

Adding this line `await conn.write(new TextEncoder().encode('Test'))` inside the for, i get to send data from the server to the client but only when the connection is made.

What I want to achieve is to be able to send information at any time, from the server to the client, but I have no idea how to achieve it, I don't get much information on the subject and my head is exploding.

From already thank you very much!

Comment: One possible way is that don't close the connection. But the client may timeout. The best way is to use web-sockets. Deno provides a standard library for [web-sockets](https://deno.land/std@0.88.0/ws)

Comment: Yes, I actually tried, but what I'm trying to do is connect it to an arduino, and I don't think websocket is the correct way to do it. It seems strange to me that I can't figure out how to do it. One basic thing to test is being able to tell when a client disconnects, but I can't even find that. I guess because it is new, documentation is missing or something like that.

Comment: Hm, if you are sending data from server to client (in one direction only) whenever the server wishes to do, you can use Server-Sent events. You can use [oak](https://deno.land/x/oak@v5.2.0/docs/sse.md) for this.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, now I'm going to review it.